# Looking for the name of this really tiny 1x2 lego part. In microbuilds it is used as wheels, but I think it may officially be an axle

Tags: part-identification, wheel, micro-scale

[image]

It's the black piece that I'm looking for the name or number of. Thank you in advance to anyone with information on this

Comment: Shouldn't that be 2x 2x 2x?

Comment: @candied_orange I assume it's step 2, and the other red pieces were placed in step 1

Comment: @RSchulz confusing out of context

Answer (score 13):

BrickLink calls it [2496 Wheel Skateboard / Trolley](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2496)

[image: 2496]

Comment: The name is a bit odd as they're also common in  "Creator" sets for micro models. They also make decent minifig scale dumbbells.

Comment: @Stephen FYI you can mark this as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.

Comment: Lego's name for it pretty much **has** to be what they originally used it for, but it's nice to have pieces that have multiple good uses as people get creative.